# add single variable to a sum google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

i have a simple p&l but i'd like to see the impact if one of the variables changes

eg

in A1 - i have sale unit price - i would like to apply that to a column of figures

if i do the normal =SUM(a1*E1) - thats ok but if i copy the sum down the column i get =SUM(A2*E2), =SUM(A3*E3) etc - i need A1 to be fixed ie: =SUM(A!*E2),=SUM(A!*E3) etc

(i could obviously copy the A1 cell down the column but everytime i want to see the changes i'd have to change all the cell contents everytime rather than just once)

Answer (score 0):

Try a formula like the following:

```
=SUM(A$1*E1)
```

Example:

[image]